# Reorder the content of Woocommerce Storefront header using remove and add action

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, storefront

I use a child theme of Storefront. I have edited a copy of the `header.php` file and I add in this part after removing the navigation bar the extra div:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" style="<?php storefront_header_styles(); ?>">
    <div class="col-full">

        <?php
        /**
         * Functions hooked into storefront_header action
         *
         * @hooked storefront_skip_links                       - 0
         * @hooked storefront_social_icons                     - 10
         * @hooked storefront_site_branding                    - 20
         * @hooked storefront_secondary_navigation             - 30
         * @hooked storefront_product_search                   - 40
         * @hooked storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper       - 42
         * @hooked storefront_primary_navigation               - 50
         * @hooked storefront_header_cart                      - 60
         * @hooked storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper_close - 68
         */
    **remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation', 50 );**
    **add_action('storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation', 51);**

    **add_action('storefront_header', 'jk_storefront_header_content', 50);**        
    do_action( 'storefront_header' ); 

        ?>          
    </div>
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

This seems correct but instead of the navigation bar to be removed and replaced I have the old navigation bar the extra div and another navigation, which means that navigation bar had never been removed…

How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to override `header.php` in your child theme…

To use properly `remove_action()`, you need to embed it in a custom function hooked in **`init`** action hook this way:

```
add_action('init', 'replace_storefront_primary_navigation' );
function replace_storefront_primary_navigation(){
    remove_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation', 50 );
    add_action('storefront_header', 'jk_storefront_header_content', 50);
}
function jk_storefront_header_content(){
    // your custom navigation code goes here
    echo '<span style="display:inline-block; padding:10px; border:solid 1px grey;">My custom mega menu goes Here</span>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works on WooCommerce Storefront theme.

Comment: I run the above from inside function.php does not add my static text div above navigation bar. Navigation bar is coming from Mega Menu plugin, does this has to do with this problem?

Comment: I really don't know about in your case… The code works on my test sever

Comment: It works partially by adding the text at the end of header always. In order to work i call the replace function from header. I placed several priorities but the same result. It is treating search, cart,navigation and logo as one.

Comment: @MariaGeorgali, you should check where the plugin print the men. It uses a hook like you.